# Add lists as variables in a dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr, mutate

I need an efficient way to add a series of variables together, preferably without a loop.

```
library(dplyr) 
avar_2000  <- c(2,5,1)
avar_2001  <- c(2,3,1)
avar_2002  <- c(7,2,5)
bvar_2000  <- c(9,1,1)
bvar_2001  <- c(5,5,3)
bvar_2002  <- c(3,8,NA)


df <- data.frame(avar_2000,avar_2001,avar_2002,bvar_2000,bvar_2001,bvar_2002)

print(df)
```

| avar_2000 | avar_2001 | avar_2002 | bvar_2000 | bvar_2001 | bvar_2002 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | 7 | 9 | 5 | 3 |
| 5 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 5 | 8 |
| 1 | 1 | 5 | 1 | 3 | NA |

```
bvars <- c ("bvar_2000","bvar_2001","bvar_2002")

df2 <- df %>% mutate (avar_sum = avar_2000 + avar_2001 + avar_2002) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate (bvar_sum = sum(across(all_of(bvars))))

print(df2)
```

| avar_2000 | avar_2001 | avar_2002 | bvar_2000 | bvar_2001 | bvar_2002 | avar_sum | bvar_sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | 7 | 9 | 5 | 3 | 11 | 17 |
| 5 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 5 | 8 | 10 | 14 |
| 1 | 1 | 5 | 1 | 3 | NA | 7 | NA |

Two puzzles:

1. How can I sum up all the avars and bvars within one line? My project has many of these series, and it would be neat if I could say, "add up all the avars into avars_sum, bvars into bvars_sum, etc.". Is that possible?
2. How can I add avars and bvars together within their respective years into a new series? As in, avar2000 + bvar2000 = cvar2000. Without writing it out and without writing a loop.

I wrote a loop and it works, but it's... well, there's a better way, right?

```
for (b in 2000:2003) {
  avar = paste0("avar_",b)
  bvar = paste0("bvar_",b)
  cvar = paste0("cvar_",b)
  
  df2<- df2%>% 
    mutate(
      !!cvar := get(avar) + get(bvar))   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the columns are in the same order, we could use

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with('avar'), 
   .names = "{str_replace(.col, 'avar', 'cvar')}") + 
      across(starts_with('bvar')))
```

-output

```
 avar_2000 avar_2001 avar_2002 bvar_2000 bvar_2001 bvar_2002 cvar_2000 cvar_2001 cvar_2002
1         2         2         7         9         5         3        11         7        10
2         5         3         2         1         5         8         6         8        10
3         1         1         5         1         3        NA         2         4        NA
```

As mentioned by @M--, if we want to do both the operations

```
df %>% 
  mutate(avar_sum = rowSums(pick(starts_with('avar')), 
   na.rm = TRUE), bvar_sum = rowSums(pick(starts_with('bvar')), 
        na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
   mutate(across(c(starts_with('avar'), -ends_with('sum')), 
   .names = "{str_replace(.col, 'avar', 'cvar')}") + 
      across(c(starts_with('bvar'), -ends_with('sum'))))
```

-output

```
 avar_2000 avar_2001 avar_2002 bvar_2000 bvar_2001 bvar_2002 avar_sum bvar_sum cvar_2000 cvar_2001 cvar_2002
1         2         2         7         9         5         3       11       17        11         7        10
2         5         3         2         1         5         8       10       14         6         8        10
3         1         1         5         1         3        NA        7        4         2         4        NA
```

---

Or another option with `dplyover`

```
library(dplyover)
df %>%
   mutate(across2(starts_with('avar'), 
    starts_with('bvar'), ~ .x + .y, .names_fn = 
      ~ str_replace(.x, "avar_(\\d+)_.*", "cvar_\\1")))
```

-output

```
avar_2000 avar_2001 avar_2002 bvar_2000 bvar_2001 bvar_2002 cvar_2000 cvar_2001 cvar_2002
1         2         2         7         9         5         3        11         7        10
2         5         3         2         1         5         8         6         8        10
3         1         1         5         1         3        NA         2         4        NA
```

---

Or in `base R`, use `split.default`

```
df[paste0("cvar_", 2000:2002)] <- lapply(split.default(df, 
      trimws(names(df), whitespace = ".*_")), rowSums)
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to implement successfully. I have a question if you don't mind: in your first solution, what is the str_replace doing, exactly? cvars don't exist yet, so this creates them?

Comment: @Andre In the first solution, the default name will be from the first `across`, so we change the column name in `.names` by replacing the substring 'avar' with `cvar` to create new columns.  if we don't do that, it will update the `avar` columns with values from `avar` + corresponding 'bvar'.  In the second solution, it is capturing the digits (`(\\d+)`) after the `avar` and remove the rest, and replace with `cvar_` and the backreference of captured as `.x` will have a combined name from both avar and bvar

Answer (score 3):

The following base R solution *just* makes it as a one-liner. I don't think you are missing an elegant dplyr solution here - the sensible way would be to pivot your data into longer format and keep it that way.

```r
sapply(unique(substr(names(df), 1, 4)), \(x) rowSums(df[grepl(x, names(df))]))
#>      avar bvar
#> [1,]   11   17
#> [2,]   10   14
#> [3,]    7   NA
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another `base` R solution which uses `rowsum` and `group` argument.

```r
t(rowsum(t(df), group = sub("_.*", "_sum", colnames(df)), na.rm = F))

#>      avar_sum bvar_sum
#> [1,]       11       17
#> [2,]       10       14
#> [3,]        7       NA
```

```
t(rowsum(t(df), group = sub(".*_", "cvar_", colnames(df)), na.rm = F))

#>      cvar_2000 cvar_2001 cvar_2002
#> [1,]        11         7        10
#> [2,]         6         8        10
#> [3,]         2         4        NA
```